# NullReferenceException on removal from ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, nullreferenceexception

In my program I have a `ListBox` that is populated with items by the user. The UserControl that owns the `ListBox` is written with an MVVM style.

Inside the Data Model, the `ListBox` has a `SelectedCommand` property that changes certain values in the Model (In turn changing the view). I also have a "Remove" button that removes this selected item.

On removal of the `SelectedCommand` I receive a `NullReferenceException`, which I'm guessing is due to how my `SelectedCommand` property is written. I'm sure the problem and how to fix it will be obvious to you guys, but to me it is not.

`SelectedCommand` Property from **Data Model**:

```
public MyCommandDefinition SelectedCommand
{
    get { return _selectedCommand; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedCommand);

        if (SelectedCommand.DisplayName == _setOutput) //**NullReferenceException on this line!
        {
            //Commands to change values in model
        }

        if(...) { ... } 
    }
}
```

The exception box reads, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I think the problem is that `SelectedCommand` becomes `null` once it is removes from the list. If I am doing data manipulations that depend on what is selected, how can I get around this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `value` is `null`. You need to account for this scenario somehow. Here is one solution:

```
public MyCommandDefinition SelectedCommand
{
    get { return _selectedCommand; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedCommand);

        if (SelectedCommand != null && SelectedCommand.DisplayName == _setOutput) 
        {
            //Commands to change values in model
        }

        if(...) { ... } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to `return` if the value is null.  Why not just use `if SelectedCommand != null && SelectedCommand.DisplayName == _setOutput` ...

Answer (score 0):

I had similary problem and found a workaround, it was caused because we can not remove current item in ItemCheck event :

```
private void myList_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // This should work
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        myList.Items.Remove(myItem);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public MyCommandDefinition SelectedCommand
{
    get { return _selectedCommand; }
    set
    {

        if (value!=null)
         {

        _selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedCommand);

        if (SelectedCommand.DisplayName == _setOutput) //**NullReferenceException on this line!
        {
            //Commands to change values in model
        }

            if(...) { ... } 
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @geng : please check it now.